# alignment of old android version

Tags: android, android-layout

hello I have a problem with checkboxes which work perfecrly fine on android 4.3 but do not work on the 2.2 version here are the pictures. The problem is that the checkbox elements are being wrapped and aligned to the left in the older versions.

[image: working 4.3 version]

[image: problematic 2.2 version]

[image: The Checkbox is not aligned to center in previous versions and is shifted]

here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layoutgravity="start" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/car"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/damage_car" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxRightFront"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CheckBoxFront"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxLeftFront"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/CheckBoxRightFront"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CheckBoxRightFront"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/CheckBoxLeftBD"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/CheckBoxLeftBD"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxBumper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CheckBoxFront"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CheckBoxFront"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxRoof"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CheckBoxBack"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxFront"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxLeftFD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CheckBoxRoof"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxLeftBD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CheckBoxBack"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CheckBoxBumper"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/CheckBoxBumper"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxRightFD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CheckBoxRoof"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CheckBoxRightBD"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/CheckBoxRightBD"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:padding="16dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxRightBD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/CheckBoxLeftBD"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CheckBoxLeftBD"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layoutCar"
        android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you share screen shot?

Comment: this is a theme padding problem

Comment: totally unrelated: but why supporting 2.2? at least increase to API 10 (2.3.3)

Comment: As @MurtazaHussain correctly noted, there is a theme change in padding sizes between pre-11 (**0dp** added), 11 (**+32dp**) and 14 (**+16dp**) API Level. **+xy**dp referred to pre-11.

Comment: Thanks for the hints but can we be more explicit of how such issues get resolved?

Comment: I put **negative** integers in `values-11` (**-32**) and `values-14` (**-16**). And **0** in the `values` folder. Then **scale** that integer (convert from px to **dp**) and finally assign it to my paddings in code.

Comment: I added a picture are you guys sure it is the theme alignment thing? or it could be just a checkbox alignment issue?

Comment: thanks for all the help it was setting me to the right path to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer for this issue at the end it was different wrapping of object on a different versions so what i did was  to cut the extra wrapping by writing the width fitting the image size and override the system default wrapping scheme

```
android:layout_width="[Image-width-size]dp"
```

in my case it was

```
android:layout_width="20dp"
```